# React-csv downloading source page HTML instead of intended csv data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, csv

I have a very large array, called data, of JS Objects (some of which include null and NaN values, I've looked into that to no avail), and am using react-csv to make a button that downloads the array as a csv file using CSVLink.

```
// parent component...
<CSVLink
    data={data}
    filename={`${name}_${location}_${abbreviation}.csv`}>
    Download Raw Data
</CSVLink>
```

When I click the button, it downloads the file okay, except that the contents of the file are what appears to be the source HTML of the entire webpage:
[image]

The objects themselves look correct (they just have some keys and values), it's only the downloaded version that looks wrong.

I've tried other libraries and nothing has worked. Maybe it's something with how React renders and hydrates stuff? Or else a problem with react-csv itself?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the package version of `react-csv` library?

Comment: react-csv: version 2.2.2
React: 18.2.0
Node: 18.18.0

Comment: You have 2 options to try-out here. First, add `headers` and `separator` props to the `CSVLink` and try it out. Second, as far I try to figure out the issue, many are pointing to downgrade the package version to `2.0.*` from `2.2.*`. Try either of these @SuperNunb

Comment: Downgrading versions worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As commentors suggested, downgrading react-csv to 2.0 worked for me. Hopefully that fixes it for anyone else looking at this question.